# change background when refreshed, but responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

i currently have this javascript code in my head tag which makes the background change every time the page is refreshed. it works great, however, i would like to have different "image sets" (1.png, 2.png, 3.png vs 1mini.png, 2mini.png, 3mini.png), one for the desktop version and another one for the mobile version. any idea on how to do this?

```
<script>
        function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
            var myImages = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", 
           "images/1mini.png", "images/2mini.png", "images/3mini.png" ]; 
            var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
            var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';}
        window.onload=changeImg;
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of srcsets? This might be a solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background image by checking if the device is mobile or desktop.

eg:

i currently have this javascript code in my head tag which makes the background change every time the page is refreshed. it works great, however, i would like to have different "image sets" (1.png, 2.png, 3.png vs 1mini.png, 2mini.png, 3mini.png), one for the desktop version and another one for the mobile version. any idea on how to do this?

```
<script>
        function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
            var mobileImages =["images/1mini.png","images/2mini.png","images/3mini.png"]; 
            var desktopImages = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png"]; 

            var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;

            //this code will return true when device is mobile
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)) { 
                var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*mobileImages.length);
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
                                  'url('+mobileImages[newImgNumber]+')';  
            }else{
               var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*desktopImages.length);
               document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
                                  'url('+desktopImages[newImgNumber]+')';
            } 
        }


}

        window.onload=changeImg;
 </script>
```

Comment: i've tried this, but it doesn't work. i'm guessing it's cause the code isn't returning true as var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length); doesn't correspond with myImages anymore

Comment: @user11136133 I have modified the above code. Try using it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
`You can go for some queries depending on your device viewport.`
    function changeBg(){
       var width = window.innerWitdh;
        var myImages = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", 
                       "images/1mini.png", "images/2mini.png", "images/3mini.png" ];
        if(width > 1200){ // lets say here is a desktop
          document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ myImages[1] +')';
        }else if(width < 1200 && width > 700){ // some smaller device
         document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ myImages[2] +')';
        }else { // this can be mobile
         document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ myImages[3] +')';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query with different css class that could be use as a background.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .img1 {
  background-image: url("1.jpg");
 }
 .img2 {
  background-image: url("2.jpg");
 }
}

.img1 {
 background-image: url("3.jpg")
 }
.img2 {
  background-image: url("4.jpg");
 }
```

And change shown classes with function.

So you have one function and it is responsive for window size without any additional methods - simply in css file.

**EDIT:**

```
<script>
    function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
        var myImages = ["img1", "img2", "img3"]; 
        var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
        document.getElementByClassName(myImages[newImgNumber]).show();}
    window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

And you put `display:none;` in your css file. So you show only background that was 'randomly' picked.

```
<html>
   <div class='background'>
     <div class="img1"/>
     <div class="img2"/>
     <div class="img3"/>
```

Something like that.

Comment: hi, this seems simple. any idea on how to incorporate those classes or img tags to the javascript code i have?

Comment: Well ofc, you can use your function - just instead of array with img create array of 'name classes' and than use random on it, So it would generete random picture on your site. Responsivness will be done automatically by media query in you css file. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Working Example

```js
    function changeImg(imgNumber) {

        var myImages = [{
                isMobile: true,
                image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg"
            },
            {
                isMobile: false,
                image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
            },
            {
                isMobile: true,
                image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTptDddyBZG4i4cycd6ZIBP2wT8PQKhihUqenZF7GpzlvTZuPghGQ"
            },
            {
                isMobile: false,
                image: "http://sfwallpaper.com/images/background-wallpaper-images-3.jpg"
            }
        ];

        var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
        var filteredArray = [];
        if (isMobile()) {
            filteredArray = myImages.filter(function(el) {
                return el.isMobile == true;
            });
        } else {
            filteredArray = myImages.filter(function(el) {
                return el.isMobile == false;
            });
        }
        var newImgNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredArray.length);
        console.log("newImgNumber", newImgNumber);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + filteredArray[newImgNumber].image + ')';
    }



function isMobile() {
    var match = window.matchMedia || window.msMatchMedia;
    if (match) {
        var mq = match("(pointer:coarse)");
        return mq.matches;
    }
    return false;
}

window.onload = changeImg;
```