# How to set image width and height using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adjust the following javascript code (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55185860/17942069) ) so the background images will fit the screen. Currently they're streched too far down. I believe the problem is in the `mobileImages.style.width`, `mobileImages.style.height` `desktopImages.width` and `desktopImages.height`. Could somebody point out my mistake(s)?

```js
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
        var mobileImages =["images/1mini.png","images/2mini.png","images/3mini.png"]; 
        mobileImages.style.width = '100vw';
        mobileImages.style.height = 'auto';
            var desktopImages = ["images/desktop/1.jpg", "images/desktop/2.jpg", "images/desktop/3.jpg", "images/desktop/4.jpg", "images/desktop/5.jpg", "images/desktop/6.jpg", "images/desktop/7.jpg", "images/desktop/8.jpg", "images/desktop/9.jpg", "images/desktop/10.jpg", "images/desktop/11.jpg", "images/desktop/12.jpg", "images/desktop/13.jpg", "images/desktop/14.jpg", "images/desktop/15.jpg", "images/desktop/16.jpg", "images/desktop/17.jpg", "images/desktop/18.jpg", "images/desktop/19.jpg", "images/desktop/20.jpg", "images/desktop/21.jpg", "images/desktop/22.jpg", "images/desktop/23.jpg", "images/desktop/24.jpg", "images/desktop/25.jpg"];
        desktopImages.width = '100vw';
        desktopImages.height = 'auto';
            var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;

            //this code will return true when device is mobile
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)) { 
                var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*mobileImages.length);
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
                                  'url('+mobileImages[newImgNumber]+')';  
            }else{
               var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*desktopImages.length);
               document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
                                  'url('+desktopImages[newImgNumber]+')';
            } 
        }


        window.onload=changeImg;
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
    <div class="containter-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="text">
                some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you better include the full code with the images. the snippet can't execute the code like this.

Answer (score 0):

u trying to apply width and height to array of images, u can set width and height only to dom nodes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take  look in the example below. It will use inline style. But you can assign some styles in your css and bind them to the image by using javascript (classList -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList?retiredLocale=de).

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
img.style.width = "200px"
img.style.height = "200px"
console.log(img)
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're styling the `array`, which does **nothing**!

### Example 1

We simply get the `img` element, then we style it *as you tried*.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('.img');
img.style.width = '200px';
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
```

### Example 2

In this example, we **append** the `img`s to the *DOM* first then we style it! **and that's the point!**

```js
// Images src
let imgs = ['https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg', 
            'https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg'];

// Array to hold HTML output (images as elements)
let holder = [];

// Create elements based on src above and push it to the array (holder) 
imgs.forEach(img => {
    let el = `<img class="imgs" src="${img}" />`;
    holder.push(el);
});

// Print the output of the holder to the DOM (HTML)
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = holder.join('');

// Get the images and set it's width
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs');
images.forEach(img => {
    img.style.width = '200px';
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

### Example 3 (based on your code)

1. First you didn't choose the `index` when you called the `function`.
2. *Remember*, you have to style the `background properties` and **NOT** width and height! since it's not an `img`! It's a `background-image`!
3. If the `index` is randomly picked, then no need for the `parameter`, get a random number and pass it as an `index`.

**Background Properties:**

- background-image
- background-position
- background-size
- background-repeat
- background-origin
- background-attachment

**If it's an `img` then make sure it's in the DOM before you can style it.**

[MDN - background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

```js
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
  var desktopImages = [
      "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg",
      "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"];
      
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ desktopImages[imgNumber] +')';
}


window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  changeImg(1)
});
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="containter-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text">
    some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```